How do I clear all windows 11 notifications from a single-source?
In my Windows 11 notifications popup, I see groups of notifications from each app. I can clear all notifications with "clear all". I can click the 'x' on each notification to clear one at a time. Is there a way to clear all notifications from a single app?
I get a notification for every email in outlook, and having new emails in outlook show the notification icon is nice, but after I've gone though outlook and handled everything for the day, how can I clear all my emails from the system notification system without manually clicking each, and without clearing notifications from other apps?

Thanks @john, if you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

It seems this may have changed for the better recently.

Open the notification tray
Hover the mouse over the notification source
Two icons appear: ... and X
Click X to clear all notifications for that source.

Example: clicking this X will clear all outlook notifications

